# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found

Tags: python, unicode, django-models, typeerror, coercion

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    movie_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    movie_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    movie_lang = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=72)
    producer = models.CharField(max_length=72)
    production_house = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    lead_actor = models.CharField(max_length=72)
    lead_actress = models.CharField(max_length=72)
    music_director = models.CharField(max_length=72)
    art_director = models.CharField(max_length=72)
    stunts = models.CharField(max_length=72)
    cinematography = models.CharField(max_length=72)
    costume_design = models.CharField(max_length=72)
    hair_stylist = models.CharField(max_length=72)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.movie_name

class Cover(models.Model):
    cover_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    cover_path = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    movie = models.ForeignKey('Movie',on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cover_id

    def unicode(self):
        return unicode(self.cover_path)




#urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.movie,name='movie'),
    url(r'^vedio/',views.vedio,name='vedio'),
    url(r'^image/',views.image,name='image'),
    url(r'^$',views.index,name = 'index'),
]

#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the movie station.")

def movie(request,question_id):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome to movies page")

def vedio(request):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome to vedios page")

def image(request):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome to images page")
```

Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/movieaware/cover/add/

Django Version: 1.10.3
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:

```
['movieaware.apps.MovieawareConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

> Traceback:
>
> File "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py"
>   in wrapper
>     544.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>     149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py"
>   in _wrapped_view_func
>     57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py"
>   in inner
>     211.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py"
>   in add_view
>     1509.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
>
> File
>   "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapper
>     67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>     149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in bound_func
>     63.                 return func.**get**(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
>
> File
>   "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in inner
>     185.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py"
>   in changeform_view
>     1453.                     self.log_addition(request, new_object, change_message)
>
> File
>   "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py"
>   in log_addition
>     719.             object_repr=force_text(object),
>
> File
>   "/home/kartheek/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py"
>   in force_text
>     78.                 s = six.text_type(s)
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/movieaware/cover/add/ Exception
>   Value: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found

I have tried most of the solutions suggested but nothing is working.
I was not able to figure out the problem

Comment: Can you show your view and your url config for /movieaware/cover/add/?

Comment: updated with view and url @ettanany

Answer (score 1):

Could it be empty perhaps?

Try this:

```
        return unicode(self.cover_path) or u''
```

The error could also happen if you try to pass an object instead of a string through "unicode".

We can't check from your code, but test for type(self.cover_path) and make sure it's a string, otherwise convert it manually to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.cover_id
```

here i was returning id of type Long for string function. It should return a string which is why it throws an error.

Comment: You can use
`return u"%s" % (self.cover_id if self.cover_id else "")`
or
`return u"{0}".format(self.cover_id if self.cover_id else "")`